# Is there any way to attract or influence iron golems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created several iron golems to protect a village, and they occasionally [get through the walls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling) (mostly cobblestone fences) I've built.  Is there any way to get them to move toward me, or toward the village, and back where they belong?  I tried holding a rose.

Comment: +1 for link explaining how mobs get through walls. It only makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, golems will only follow you if you've attacked them, which isn't recommended. There's no peaceful way to make them follow you.

Like every mob, though, they can be moved with water streams. Trap them and build a canal to bring them back to the village. Or, if you want their iron, trap them and move them *away* from the village. Once they are far enough they don't count for the golem spawn limit anymore and new ones will spawn to replace them. Then you can build a crusher to "peacefully" dispose of your extra golems and harvest their iron and roses.

Comment: I like the stream idea.  Now I understand why the villagers use raised beds!

Answer (score 7):

Use a [lead](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lead). It works in the new update.

Comment: How? What do you need to do with it? How do you make one? :)

Comment: Works as of 1.7.4, may work earlier.  Have not tested.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Minecraft 1.6+ try using a lead to pull them.

You make a lead with 4 string (S) and 1 slimeball (O):

```
S S _
S O _
_ _ S
```

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! When you want to answer a question, it's best practice to read the answers already posted. If you see that what you were going to say has already been said, there's no need to post a duplicate answer unless you're adding new info. The edit you made was a good move though it's always best to use correct grammar, and remember that a picture speaks a thousand words - a screen cap of the crafting grid and a [link to the wiki page](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Lead) would work well here. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Use fishing rods and water canals to move mobs. You can also push them (TAKES TIME!).

Comment: A good idea, but unfortunately the fishing rod doesn't really work.  The hit pushes them away, and pulling them back moves them only a short distance.  You can make a little headway if you push from one side then run around and pull from the other, but it's not any faster than pushing. :(

Answer (score 1):

Make trench 2 deep and fill with water so that they are pushed back and to make sure they don't escape again make your fence 2 high

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way where you can leash the iron golem(s) and take themail wherever you would like. In this way, you can drag them where you desire in an easy way, though I am not sure whether this is safe in survival mode.

Answer (score 0):

I use wooden fences, and have not had escape issues.  I would assume your mileage with cobblestone fences should be consistent.  I've had two issues in the past that have caused villagers and golems to "escape":

- Endermen leaving dirt/sand blocks adjacent to fences.
- Having to build double high fences along changes in elevation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the slopes in my case, too.  It's easy to make a combination of blocks and fences that looks fine but in fact lets mobs through if they jump and move just right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you ever have this problem on creative mode, then spawn monsters, since Iron Golems like to go after monsters. But make sure the monster is in a fenced area to prevent it from jumping out and attacking your villagers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Lead it helps. I used it to make Iron and Snow Golems to follow me.